# How to fix a repeatedly hacked gmail account (where 2FA is enabled and passwords are changed)?

Tags: google, multi-factor, gmail

A friend of mine came to me for help with this issues. Her Gmail account has been hacked and keeps sending out spam emails to her contacts. This is happening to her on a monthly basis. Each time it happens she changes her password. She also went through and tweaked all her security settings. However, even after having done all this repeatedly, when she goes into her "Device activity" in her Google Account settings, it keeps showing an unauthorized Android device that belongs to the hacker. It doesn't give her the option to remove it from her devices either.

It looks like the emails aren't being sent from her device (they're sending spam emails to her whole address book and spoofing the from address to make it appear to come from her). However, we still want to know how to rid this device from her account.

[image: Devices & Activity]

Comment: my first thought is 'application passwords' that bypass 2FA - are there any listed for her account? can she disable them?

Comment: She revoked application passwords last time this happened

Comment: @BrettG She must revoke the access from the rogue android phone...see my answer for details and links

Answer (score 7):

She must be missing something...let us try this:

First read about the google answer on "someone is sending spam from my email"  [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50200?hl=en) as they state it there: "

1. The message was spoofed, forging your address as the sender.
2. The original sender used your address as a reply-to address so that responses would be sent to you.

Neither of these possibilities indicates that your account was compromised..."

There are two ways to check for that:

1. Get a copy of the email, including headers, and check the originating IP address to see if it was not one you could have been using
2. If you’re receiving bounce messages from a bunch of email addresses for people you’ve never heard of

If your account was spoofed, they simply created an email that had fake details (usually the “From” or “Reply-to” address), and there is very little you can do to stop this.

If in fact your account have been hacked follow this:

- While logged in the account you want to manage access:
- https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 = here you can review all APPs phones and sites that are connect to your account and you can remove this rogue android from here just click on "Android" then revoke access
- https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#devices = here you can check the phone that is being used for 2 way authentication and make sure you still have 10 reservation codes
- https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#registered = here make sure you make google ask for the code in all computers except the one you are using
- Now change your password this should log you out of any connected device and with the 2 way aunthentication they should not be able to get in again

Now if this don't work then we can suspect that the attacker may be regaining the password after she changes it (e.g compromising her pc or if she changes to a not so different password he may be able to brute force it again fast phishing attacks and etc ) if thats the case then i  recommend the usual : only change the password via a phone and do some AV scan on all her pcs.

Another possibility is that her password has been leaked on another site especially if she reuse her password everywhere so she may want to choose for a unique password for gmail for now.

Answer (score 2):

I think your friend has a phone hacked: a malware can stealthly receive and conceal 2-factor codes, then transmitting them to the attacker

Comment: This is exactly what is happening to me. I removed gmail from my phone completely and will no longer use any services on the phone that is linked to my account. Of course having said that, one cannot then use Google App store etc. But it is possible to use a proxy account. The other issue is that since my account has been hacked, ALL my documents on Google drive have most probably ALSO been compromised!! The FORCED tie-in of the gmail account with other services is a good idea for google as a business, but a terrible one security wise.

Comment: Was the phone hacked or just the number slammed ?